# Java- Improper Neutralization of Special Elements used in an SQL Command ('SQL Injection') (CWE ID 89) Veracode Static issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, veracode

After running a Vercode report
After R&D I didn't get solution for this.

**Description**
This database query contains a SQL injection flaw. The function call constructs a dynamic SQL query using a variable
derived from untrusted input. An attacker could exploit this flaw to execute arbitrary SQL queries against the database.

**Recommendations**
Avoid dynamically constructing SQL queries. Instead, use parameterized prepared statements to prevent the database
from interpreting the contents of bind variables as part of the query. Always validate untrusted input to ensure that it
conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible

I am using a common method to get the Resultset from database in many modules so I cant create my sql query in this method only, Is there any way to sanitize this user input in this method itself in order to resolve this High Veracode vulnerabiliy.
please suggest.

---

```
 public ResultSet fetchDB(String sql){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        logger.info("DB connection checking");
        if(con == null || con.isClosed()) {
            con = getDBConnection();
            logger.info("DB connection established");
        }
        logger.info("Executing statement");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        logger.info("DB data fetching completed");
        return rs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
  }
```

Comment: Use of `stmt.executeQuery(sql)` indicates your queries would contain values already which is a huge vulnerability. Not sure if that's the only thing that triggers vera code though. You should try to use `PreparedStatement` instead and try passing a list of positional parameters and set them via `setObject(index + 1, parameters[index])`

Comment: @Thomas As I am using this method in multiple locations so I can't send a proper positional parameters and set in that method only. Is there any way that we can sanitize this input (String sql) in this method only

Comment: Sanitizing the SQL may be hard as you probably don't know what queries to allow. You could use some parsing to see just keep the first select query (as injection attacks could insert malicious queries into the data) but that can become quite complex and might mean a significant performance hit. In any case you'd probably still get the vulnerability flag as this doesn't fix the basic problem.

Comment: So I'd rather work on getting rid of this method and fix all the code instead trying to work around this tech debt (the workaround could be used as an intermediate measure but should not be the ultimate "fix").